# How to perform an operation on each line in every file in a directory ending with a particular extension?

Tags: python

I would like to perform an operation on each *line* for all files ending with an extension (pdb) from a particular directory. In my following code, what I can understand is that just *{lines = pdbinput.read()}* will not allow me to perform a startswith() operation on a *line* in *lines*.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("F:/python")
for files in glob.glob("*.pdb"):
    with open(files) as pdbinput:
        lines = pdbinput.read()
        with open ('output.txt', 'w') as f1:
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("HETATM"):
                    print (line, file=f1)
```

But it allows me to print *lines* directly:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("F:/python")
for files in glob.glob("*.pdb"):
    with open(files) as pdbinput:
        lines = pdbinput.read()
        with open ('modified.txt', 'w') as f1:
            print (lines, file=f1)
```

Comment: What do you mean that it "will not allow" you to do `line.startswith()`? Did it have no effect? Did it produce an error? Be more specific.

Comment: If you are looking for modifying the file's contents in-place, have a look at the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module, which offers a way to do this, and also incidentally would simplify your code significantly.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying this. The first case, it doesn't give any sort of output while in the second case, it does give an output by printing all the lines of each every file ending with the extension "pdb".

Answer (score 0):

`pdbinput.read()` reads the entire file into a single string. That means that the subsequent `for line in lines` will iterate over that string character by character, not line by line.

You could either use `pdbinput.readlines()` or (the usual way) iterate over the file directly:

```
with open(files) as pdbinput:
    with open ('output.txt', 'w') as f1:
        for line in pdbinput:
            if line.startswith("HETATM"):
                print (line, file=f1)
```

The next problem: right now, for each PDB file, a new `output.txt` is generated, overwriting the previous one. Just move that `with` block outside of the iteration:

```
with open ('output.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for files in glob.glob("*.pdb"):
        with open(files) as pdbinput:
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("HETATM"):
                    print (line, file=f1)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! This is exactly where I was stuck! :)